Mineflayer-pathfinder the bot doesn't want to go
When my bot goes 10 blocks - it should go another 20 blocks, but it does not move at all after going through the first 10 blocks! I tried a lot of things - but it does not want to move at all after going through the first 10 blocks. What am I doing wrong? I wanted to learn how to make the bot follow a route that I specify, like first 10 blocks forward, then 5 blocks back and so on.
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals: { GoalBlock } } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
host: 'localhost', // minecraft server ip
 port: '3333',
username: 'test', // minecraft username
 })

 bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)

 bot.once('spawn', () => {
 const defaultMove = new Movements(bot)
 bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove)

 const startPosition = bot.entity.position
  console.log(startPosition)

 // Первая цель - 10 блоков вперед
 const targetPosition1 = startPosition.offset(10, 0, 0)
  bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalBlock(targetPosition1.x, targetPosition1.y,        tar      getPosition1.z))

 // Добавляем обработчик события для достижения первой цели
 bot.on('goal_reached', (arg) => {
  const startPosition2 = bot.entity.position
  const targetPosition2 = startPosition2.offset(20, 0, 0)
   bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalBlock(targetPosition2.x, targetPosition2.y,   targetPosition2.z))

 console.log('Прошел 10 шагов', startPosition2)
  })
})

bot.on('kicked', (info) => {
 console.log(`Бота кикнули из сервера ${info}`)
 })

 bot.on('error', console.log)


The issue you're facing stems from how the goal system in mineflayer-pathfinder works. When the bot reaches the first goal, you correctly set the new goal for moving another 20 blocks. However, the goal_reached event is fired after the bot reaches a goal, and if you directly update the goal in the same event handler without making sure the bot has stopped processing the first path, it might cause conflicts or lead to no movement for the next goal.
You can introduce a slight delay or better control over when to set the new goal, allowing the bot to finish its current action properly before moving on to the next task.
bot.once('goal_reached', () => {
    console.log('Reached first goal at 10 blocks')

    // Wait a second before setting the next goal of 20 blocks
    setTimeout(() => {
        const startPosition2 = bot.entity.position
        const targetPosition2 = startPosition2.offset(20, 0, 0)
        bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalBlock(targetPosition2.x, targetPosition2.y, targetPosition2.z))

        console.log('Setting second goal: 20 blocks forward')
    }, 1000)
})



